# Java library to download file on restricted speed

Tags: library, java, http, url, maven

I want to develope Java program that downloads files from the given URLs with custom restricted speed. What Java libraries should I use to do so(restricted speed)? Thank you

Comment: When reading the download `InputStream` you can decide on your own when to sleep to achieve a certain download speed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37496058/limiting-inputstream